# Expose module to outside remove alias

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, require

i've index.js file which is the "main entry" to my NPM module

in the index.js I've the following code

**index.js**

```
var server = module.exports = {};

server.load = require("./controller/loader");
```

**loader.js**

```
function add(args) {
    loadFolder(args.path);
}
module.exports = {
    add:add
}
```

the module which consume my module (as node dependencies on package.json ) do the following

```
var aMoudle = require("myModule");

aMoudule.load.add({path:__dirname + '/module'});
```

This is **working OK** but my question if there is a way somehow to remove the **load** which used in `aMoudule.load.add`? 
and to do instead the `aModule.add` (but of course to keep the `add` inside the `loader` and dont put it inside my index.js which can be a solution but I want to avoid it...:-) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use :

```
server.load = require("./controller/loader");
```

all the exported members of loader will be stored in server.load variable
and hence if you have to invoke add you need to use:

```
require('myModule').load.add()
```

instead export the add method itself from loader as below:

```
server.add = require("./controller/loader").add
```

so that only the add method itself and you could access the add method directly as below:

```
require('myModule').add()
```

Comment: Can you edit your proposed answer to expand on what this does and how it addresses the OP?